# Bootstrap navbar-toggler-icon not visible but functioning normally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I am trying to get my bootstrap navbar implemented into my handlebars layout file. I've noticed some weird things happening with bootstrap and this is no exception. Once I shrink my window to a size where the navbar-toggler-icon should show, it is not visible, but it is still functioning there like it should, I just can't see it.

Here is my entire layout.hbs class:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </div>
    </nav>
    {{{body}}}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of whats happening:
[Picture of whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZafG.png)
I was told changing my navbar class to `navbar-inverse` would make it appear but I had no luck with this either.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try using `navbar navbar-light` instead of `navbar navbar-inverse`.

Bootstrap 4 is a major rewrite of the older Bootstrap and this was changed

[Bootstrap Migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#navbar)

Answer (score 2):

For Bootstrap 4:
change your bootstrap class on this line `<nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">` as shown below:

- `<nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">`

Comment: I guess `navbar-inverse` is not a part of bootstrap 4 and you might be using alpha version.